# image not deployed to firebase hosting

Tags: image, deployment, firebase

My Questions is very similar to this one:
[Images not showing up in hosted site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140049/images-not-showing-up-in-hosted-site)
and
[Images not showing up on firebase hosted webiste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650639/images-not-showing-up-on-firebase-hosted-webiste)

However, there are no answers.  So..  I have deployed my very basic site to firebase and my images folder was not uploaded.

this is my firebase.json:

> {   "firebase": "jj-contacts-example",   "public": "public",
>   "ignore": [
>       "firebase.json",
>       "**/.*",
>       "**/node_modules/**"
>    ]
>   }

This is my project structure:

- public

  - images
  - css
  - mocks
  - script
  - templates
- source

Everything else seems to have uploaded correctly
Is there any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: I am having same issue, did you find any fix?